# Trignometry&Matrices

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, determinant

-I'm confused with this problem I know $|adj (adjA)|=  |A|^{\left(n-1\right)^{2}}$
i tried opening determinant but it doent seem to help much.

-If $3\sin \alpha \sin \beta  + 4\cos \beta  + 5\cos \alpha \sin \beta  = 5\sqrt 2$   $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$, then $|adj (adjA)|$ is equal to
[The matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfDcL.png)

[The question i am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnxui.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,\,\,\mathsf{\vec{a}=3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+5\hat{k}}\,\,\,$ and $\,\,\,\mathsf{\vec{b}=sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{i}+cos(\beta)\hat{j}+cos(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{k}}\,\,\,$

Now, $$\mathrm{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=3\,sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)+4\,cos(\beta)+5\,cos(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)=5\sqrt{2}}$$

And,$$\mathrm{\left|\vec{a}\right|=\sqrt{(3)^2+(4)^2+(5)^2}=5\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\mathrm{\left|\vec{b}\right|=\sqrt{sin^2(\alpha)\cdot sin^2(\beta)+cos^2(\beta)+cos^2(\alpha)\cdot sin^2(\beta)}}$$

$$\mathrm{\implies\left|\vec{b}\right|=\sqrt{\{sin^2(\alpha)+cos^2(\alpha)\}\cdot sin^2(\beta)+cos^2(\beta)}}$$

$$\mathrm{\implies\left|\vec{b}\right|=\sqrt{sin^2(\beta)+cos^2(\beta)}}$$

$$\mathrm{\implies\left|\vec{b}\right|=1}$$

Now, let us find the angle between the given vectors,

$\mathrm{\therefore\,cos(\theta)=\left|\dfrac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}|\cdot|\vec{b}|}\right|}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,cos(\theta)=\left|\dfrac{5\sqrt{2}}{1\cdot5\sqrt{2}}\right|}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,cos(\theta)=1}$

So, angle between the vectors $\,\,\vec{a}\,\,$ and $\,\,\vec{b}\,\,$ is $\,\,0^{o}$

That means the vectors $\,\,\vec{a}\,\,$ and $\,\,\vec{b}\,\,$ are parallel

So,

$\mathrm{\vec{a}=\lambda\,\vec{b}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,where\,\,\lambda\,\,is\,\,a\,\,real\,\,constant}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+5\hat{k}=\lambda\left(sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{i}+cos(\beta)\hat{j}+cos(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{k}\right)}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}+5\hat{k}=\lambda\,sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{i}+\lambda\,cos(\beta)\hat{j}+\lambda\,cos(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\hat{k}}$

On comparing the components, we get,

$\mathrm{3=\lambda\,sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)\,\,\,\,\,\&\,\,\,\,\,4=\lambda\,cos(\beta)}$

Put the value of $\lambda$

$\mathrm{\implies\,3=\dfrac{4}{cos(\beta)}\cdot sin(\alpha)\,sin(\beta)}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,3=4\,sin(\alpha)\,tan(\beta)}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,sin(\alpha)\,tan(\beta)=\dfrac{3}{4}}$

Now, we have,

$\mathrm{A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{sin(\alpha)}&\mathrm{-\dfrac{1}{2}}\\\mathrm{\dfrac{1}{2}}&\mathrm{tan(\beta)}\end{array}\right]}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,|A|=\left|\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{sin(\alpha)}&\mathrm{-\dfrac{1}{2}}\\\mathrm{\dfrac{1}{2}}&\mathrm{tan(\beta)}\end{array}\right|}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,|A|=sin(\alpha)\cdot tan(\beta)-\dfrac{1}{4}}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,|A|=\dfrac{3}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4}}$

$\mathrm{\implies\,|A|=\dfrac{1}{2}}$

Hence, $\,\,\mathrm{|adj\left(adj(A)\right)|=\left|A\right|=\dfrac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.The vectos approach was reaaly awesome

Comment: I'm a student of class 12.. Please don't call me 'sir'!

Comment: Please answer my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268413/if-h-n-represents-the-sum-of-the-homogeneous-products-of-n-dimensions-of-x

Comment: ok, i am a student of 12th too and sorry but i cant help u in ur question.

Comment: Refer the question to anybody who can!